# Error: Import block target does not exist - terraform layer for python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to add python klayer to lambda in terraform (as in snapshot done on console) but its giving error on terraform plan (Error: Import block target does not exist) (The target for the given import block does not exist)

I am not sure what is the correct terraform code for it, I tried to import and terraform plan failed.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import {
  to =   aws_lambda_function.lambda_function
  #to = aws_lambda_layer_version.test_layer
  id = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p311-requests:3"
}
```

Comment: That is a Lambda layer in someone else's AWS account. They are sharing the layer publicly, so you can include it with your AWS Lambda deployments by referencing the Lambda layer's ARN. However you **cannot** import the layer into your Terraform state, because that would mean your Terraform is now managing that layer, which isn't possible since the layer is not in your AWS account.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited after seeing MarkB's comment on the question)

You are trying to import someone else's layer into your Terraform state, which you can't do because it's not in your account.

To make use of that layer, you don't need to import it at all, you can just list its ARN directly in the Lambda Function definition:

```
locals {
  # We use this layer because ...
  klayers_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p311-requests:3"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...
  layers = [local.klayers_arn]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marko, this step is now working. Now I am having an issue
Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object 
Here is the code:
MODULE:
layers                  = [var.lambda_layer_arn]
MAIN
 resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "klayers" {
  layer_name = "Klayers-p3.9-requests"
  }
import {
  to =  aws_lambda_layer_version.klayers
  #id = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p39-requests:19"
  id = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p311-requests:4"
  }

Comment: Thanks Marko, this step is now working. Now I am having an issue

Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object . While attempting to import an existing object to "aws_lambda_layer_version.klayers"

Here is the code:

MODULE:
layers                  = [var.lambda_layer_arn]

MAIN
 resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "klayers" {
  layer_name = "Klayers-p3.9-requests"
  }
import {
  to =  aws_lambda_layer_version.klayers
  #id = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p39-requests:19"
  id = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p311-requests:4"
  }

Comment: @Umar I've just changed my answer after seeing the comment from MarkB

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your guidance, I am sure, as you said, if we list the ARN it should work. I will try it out and share result.

The method however, I used is different as under. Created a klayer, zipped, placed in S3 and referenced it and it worked.

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "klayers" {
  layer_name          = "Lambda-Layer"
  s3_bucket           = "abcd"
  s3_key              = "abcd/requests.zip"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.9"]
  description         = "Lambda Layer for Python Requests"
}
```